# Change CSS for Android phones

Tags: javascript, android, mobile, browser-detection

I'm losing it.

This is the code I have put in:

```
    var ua = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();
var isAndroid = ua.indexOf("android") > -1; //&& ua.indexOf("mobile");
if(isAndroid) {
 $(".menu_div").hide();
    $( ".mobile_menu" ).show();

}
```

Now, I know the detect works because the original code was a redirect that worked perfectly. However when I added in the CSS change, it stops working. ANy idea why?

I have a lovely little fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/TYJ4X/

Thanks so much!

Comment: your fiddle does not include jquery.

Comment: ... which would have been pretty obvious if you'd checked the browser console.

Comment: The code seems fine. Perhaps you're executing it before the DOM is ready, so $(' ... ') has no elements.

Comment: Blarg. So it seems to work perfectly on the Fiddle, but when I export the same code into Joomla the whole thing dies a horrible death and fails. I would assume theres a conflict somewhere, but I've done everything I can think of to fix it and it still fails.